# how can my source be at java 1.7 but compiled at 1.6

Tags: java, eclipse

I use eclipse Luna running on java 1.7. 
My project build path is 1.7.
My compiler compliance level for the project is 1.6. (both generated .class files compatibility and source compatibility).
How is it that eclipse indicates 'References to generic type JList should be parameterized' although generics for JList did not come out until 1.7?
Shouldn't the compliance (especially the source compatibility) conform to 1.6?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of your build path. 
"My compiler compliance level for the project is 1.6.", that's why it will compile, iff your code is expressed in correct Java 1.6 syntax, regardless of the Java version in build path. [Further reading.](https://blog.ajduke.in/2013/04/28/setting-up-new-java-compiler-and-runtime-in-eclipse-ide/)

Comment: I may be a little slow here but if generics for JList did not come out until 1.7 then I'm thinking it shouldn't compile in with a 1.6 compliance.  A compiler compliance of 1.6 should not allow things that are not valid for it is how I'm looking at it.  Appreciate further explanation.